# configurable product always shows out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9

I've set my configurable product on "in stock" but it still shows out of stock! :S I don't understand why.. I don't have this issue with "simple producht"

Comment: all the children products of your configurable product should be in stock check all children are all of them in stock?

Comment: I just want to make a product where you can choose a color.. I don't understand what you mean with the children products?

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was because the child products were not assigned to a Website. Be sure to associate your parent product to a website before quick creation of your child products. If you didn't do that, go back and edit each child and ensure it is attached to a website.

Comment: Yes, thank you. There was a patch of product that I imported via CSV and some simple product didn't have values in the `website` column and therefore they were not assigned to any website.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a grasp of what Configurable product is and when you need to use it and when not. and what it is doing:

suppose you have a Tshirt,the configurable product is Tshirt with attribute "color"

- tshirt 1 has yellow and red so you have two different simple products here
- tshirt 2 has green blue you have two different simple products here
- tshirt 3 has black you have one simple product here

you need a parent product of Tshirt which is a **configurable** product
and **simple** products of tshirt1, tshirt2,tshirt3

see this diagram:
[image]

if you are confused you can do it simpler like this:

[image]
Here the configurable product is a Tshirt and Tshirt has two different colors and so two different simple products

so you have to know that each one of associated products should have QTY now look at this one:

[image]

as you are seeing when you created your configurable products you should assign your simple products to it in **associated products** section and then you should have QTY in each one of simple products more than zero
also remember that the simple products visiblity should be **not visible indivudually** bcause you don't want to show each one , one by one

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just wanted to share what was eventually wrong.  As well as everything above, you have to make sure that your associated simple products are in a category.  If they are not, then the configurable product will show as out of stock.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change the `stock status` for the configurable product (Magento 2.3.0)

Answer (score -2):

In magento simple products can  be not assigned to  category.May be it's an index issue, try to  re-index product flat.